# Get the MySQL path

Tags: mysql, linux, terminal, command

I tried googling to get the MySql path, but it was unsuccessful. Is there a **unix** command, where I can find the MySQL database directory path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query,

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';`

Comment: `datadir` gives you the path to data, `basedir` gives you the path to installed location (ie from where service runs).

Comment: @Baconator507 this is run from inside mysql.

Answer (score 4):

Find the my.cnf and then find the datadir

```
sudo find / -name "my.cnf" | xargs cat | grep "datadir" | cut -d" " -f2
```

or if you know the location of the configuration file

```
cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf | grep "datadir" | cut -d" " -f2
```

Comment: What if the location of my.cnf is different? What if the user doesn't know the path of my.cnf? Is there a command to find the right path of my.cnf? I know we can use the command `locate my.cnf`, ut what if it gives me multiple locations? How will i know which path of `my.cnf` to use to get the location of the desired db?

Comment: you can run a find to find it, the line that says datadir will tell you where is db located

Answer (score 1):

If MySQL service is started, then you can use this command to get the path -

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'basedir';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mysql <<< "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';" | grep "datadir" | cut -c9-
```

or in bash

```
MYSQL_DATA_DIR="$(sudo mysql <<< "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';" | grep "datadir" | cut -c9-)"
```